# How to consume the REST API of QnA Maker to update my Knowledge Base using native JavaScript?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to consume [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/nodejs) to update the Knowledge Base I created via QnA Maker. There's a link there to go to the [API testing console](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff/console).

I'm trying to use the code below to replace the contents of my Knowledge Base with something that I pull from a different data source. See my code below. *hopefully it makes sense*

```
function synchronize() {

    var jsonData = {
        "add": {
            "qnaList":[
                {"source": "Custom"},
                {"answer": "Hello"},
                {"questions": ["Hi", "Hello"]}
            ],
        },
        "delete": {
            "sources": ["Custom"]
        },
        "update": {}
    }   

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    var parameters = {
        "body": jsonData
    }
    request.open("POST", "https://qnawcfaq.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/{kbId}}/generateAnswer", true);                    
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "EndpointKey {key}}");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");                    
    request.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
}
```

I am expecting something like the following:

```
{
  "operationState": "NotStarted",
  "createdTimestamp": "2018-03-19T07:38:46Z",
  "lastActionTimestamp": "2018-03-19T07:39:29Z",
  "userId": "86bb8390-56c0-42c2-9f81-3de161981191",
  "operationId": "03a4f4ce-30a6-4ec6-b436-02bcdf6153e1"
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Authorization"
  }
}
```

The value that I used in the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key works against their API Testing Console but it doesn't work with the code above. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

> **Working Solution Uploaded in Github**:
>   [Solution](https://github.com/ericute/chatbot)

Comment: you uri is wrong and the header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" to

Comment: @FrV, can you provide the correct uri and header? Can you provide an example please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1**: After reading the question again, questioner wants to create a QnAMaker pair and not just query it. The documentation of QnAMaker API is not really good and in some ways outdated or confusing. Hence I share hints for both scenarios.

### Scenario 1: Creating QnAMaker pairs

To create QnAMaker pairs it's a bit more difficult and I would recommend starting with the [C# Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-publish-answer) and its [Program.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-qnamaker-csharp/blob/master/documentation-samples/tutorials/create-publish-answer-knowledge-base/QnaMakerQuickstart/Program.cs). From there you can tansform it to java script. The documentation has samples for other languages as well, e.g. for [nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/nodejs).

**Protip:** Run Fiddler along while you execute the samples. This way you can check call by call and port to postman or composer for your tests.

**Based on the original question, a correct call goes like this:**

```
// Replace {key} with your QnAMaker endpoint key 
// and {kbId} with the id of the knowledgebase you want to upgrade.

function synchronize() {
    var jsonData = {
        qnaList: [
          {
            id: 0,
            answer: 'Hello',
            source: 'Custom Editorial',
            questions: [
              'Hi','Hello'
            ],
            metadata: [
              {
                name: 'category',
                value: 'api'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();    

    request.open("PATCH", "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/{kbId}", true);                    
    request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{key}");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");                    
    request.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    }

    request.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}
```

### Scenario 2: Query QnAMaker

For `POST /generateAnswer`, `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is obsolete and you have to use your own uri (host) instead of `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`.

When QnAMaker became GA summer last year, the header and host definition changed.

The easiest way to find the correct settings for all of your parameters is to go to the QnAMaker portal an click **View Code** on your knowledge base. 
[image]

From there you'll find the correct settings to copy it over.
[image]

The side by side comparison of the changed definition below was posted on [GA announcement](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/announcing-general-availability-of-qnamaker/).

[image: Announcement]

Comment: I tried doing the below changes:

`
request.open("POST", "{HOST_URL}", true);
request.setRequestHeader("POST", "{POST_VALUE}");
request.setRequestHeader("Host", "{HOST_VALUE}");
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AUTH_VALUE");
`

...but I got the following error:

`
Refused to set unsafe header "Host"
`

Comment: Hi @ericute. Host is not a header. It is part of the url https://{host}/knowledgebases/xxx. okay?

Comment: @ericute Updated my answer to make this part more clear. If you still have problems, please share your complete codebase and I'll have a look.

Comment: so I edited it a bit more.

```
request.open("POST", "https://qnawcfaq.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker", true);
request.setRequestHeader("POST", "https://qnawcfaq.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/{kbId}/generateAnswer");
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "EndpointKey {KEY}");
```

I got this error:
```
405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I appreciate all your help, man.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something here: You have to 
`request.Open("POST", "https://qnawcfaq.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/{kbId}/generateAnswer")`. The only header your need to set (beside content-type) is `("Authorization", "EndpointKey {KEY}")` as you did. Remove the rest.

Comment: I just tried exactly that. I got the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Authorization"
  }
}

Comment: Okay - I think we have to work on the code. Can you check in your code on a GitHub repo and send me the link?

Comment: Or quickly paste it here: https://codeshare.io/2pjMbE 
Please paste everything, not just snippets.

Comment: I can't paste it in your link. I created a github repo here: https://github.com/ericute/chatbot

Comment: I also updated the original post with the function I'm using together with the new errors I got.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I've not read your question correctly. You want to create a pair and not query it, correct?

Comment: Send you a PR: https://github.com/ericute/chatbot/pull/1 
The call now executes fine. However, based on APIs nature you might have to do more then just this call. See my updated answer to guide on how to approach. I think your question is answered in its context. I recommend that you go on with this working sample and in case you can't make it, raise a new question with the updated code or come back later. Would you mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: thank you for your help! I got my code working now based on your PR. :D